# wxpython frame close after idle for a while

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a wxpython GUI frame which disappear after idling for like 30seconds.
But the python program is still running just without the frame window.
I inserted print statements to my every event handler.
But no message was shown in the terminal.
I also commented all the frame Destroy and Close statement in my GUI module.

wx.App for this program was instantiated long before this GUI Frame.
Can anyone help by giving some clues ?
I am running the program with python 3.7 on Win10.  My wxpython is 4.1.1.
Also the GUI frame and the program runs in the same thread.  The GUI frame is not a child thread of the main program in this implementation.

The frame class of the GUI is roughly as follows with many details removed. The problem happen when all the code executed in the following two cases. 1. compiled to PYC file and executed from terminal. (my teammate said it always close in this case.) 2. executed as py script in vscode. ( i noticed that it sometimes close.) But the close happened after the mainloop is exited once and entered again.

```
class TaaDGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        global baseFrame 
        global basePanel 

        if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
            TaaDGUI.__init__(self, None, title="v2 GUI")
        else: 
            super( TaaDGUI, self ).__init__(None, title="v3 GUI") 
        self.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 255, 200 ) )

        self.SetSize((800,600))
        self.SetIcon(myICO)

        self.menubar = myTaaDMenubar(self)
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.framePanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    
        self.headMessage = wx.StaticText(self.framePanel, size=(800,16), 
            label = "Please take your actions!", 
            style = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    
        self.frameSizer.Add(self.headMessage) 
        self.testLogScrolledPanel = self.guiScrolledPanel(self.framePanel, 
400, 300)

        self.mainScreenAndLogSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
        self.mainScreenAndLogSizer.Add(self.mainScreenAndStatusSizer)
        self.mainScreenAndLogSizer.Add(self.testLogScrolledPanel)
        self.frameSizer.Add(self.mainScreenAndLogSizer)

        self.statusCtrl = wx.StaticText(self.framePanel, size=(400,50))
        self.textInputCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.framePanel, 
            style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, size=(360,50))

        self.buttonTextInput = textInputButton(self.__TaaD, self.framePanel)
        self.statusSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.statusSizer.Add(self.statusCtrl)

        self.statusSizer.Add(baseFrame.textInputCtrl)
        self.statusSizer.Add(self.buttonTextInput)
        self.frameSizer.Add(self.statusSizer)

        # .... some code deleted
```

[The following is the GUI that I created with some secret deleted according to my boss.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AP7a.png)

Thanks

Farn

Comment: try adding some screenshot..

Comment: We are going to have to see your code. Do you have this issue, if you run your program from the command line?

Comment: Thanks for the message.  But the code is quite big, a few thousand lines.  
 I don't know my boss would like to reveal the code.  
But the problem happen when all the code executed in the following two cases. 
1. compiled to PYC file and executed from terminal. (my teammate said it always close in this case.)
2. executed as py script in vscode.  ( i noticed that it sometimes close.)  
But the close happened after the mainloop is exited once and entered again.

Comment: Do you have a sys.exit() command somewhere? Or a wx.GetApp().Exit()?

Comment: I fail to see how you managed to write "a few thousand lines" without noticing this issue. This must have started to occur at some point recently. If you can pinpoint when, hopefully that will give a clue, as to what changed to cause it.